# Map/Diagram PL/SQL Call Stacks

Tags: plsql, documentation

I've recently inherited a collection of PL/SQL packages/procedures. Most operations involve one procedure calling another procedure which calls a third procedure, etc. I'm sure it made sense originally, but I'm struggling to get a good overall view.

Does anyone know of any software that maps/diagrams out the permutations of procedure call stacks in a visual way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out about a view called dba_dependencies from http://www.dba-oracle.com/d_dba_dependencies.htm which appears to contain a raw form much of what I'm looking for. (The one drawback is it shows what packages are called by a specific package, not what procedures in a package are called by a specific procedure in a package.)